# In lightning component <a> tag with href is not working for community page while is working for standalone app in salesforce

Tags: lightning

```
<aura:component  implements="ForceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div class="slds-var-p-around_xx-large">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-align--absolute-center">
            <div class="one" id="anchor-name">
                <a href="https://www.google.com#anchor-name">
                    <div class="slds-col" style="width:400px;height:300px;">               
                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="width:380px;height:300px; ">
                            <span class="slds-text-color_inverse">Click here to Access Humira Program</span>          
                        </div>         
                    </div>
                </a>           
            </div>
            <div class="one">
                <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">
                    <div class="slds-col" style="width:400px;height:300px;">               
                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="width:380px;height:300px; ">
                            <span class="slds-text-color_inverse">Click here to Access Skyrizi Program</span>          
                        </div>         
                    </div>
                </a>    
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is known issue with anchor tag href attribute. You should use navigation service instead. You can check documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags_a.htm).

> Don’t hard code or dynamically generate Salesforce URLs in the href
>   attribute of an  tag. Use events, such as force:navigateToSObject
>   or force:navigateToURL, instead.
>
> Using the href attribute of an  tag leads to inconsistent behavior
>   in different apps and shouldn’t be relied on.
>
> Use the navigation service for consistent linking behavior across
>   Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

Update after checking code:

Below code is working in community portal.

```
<aura:component  implements="ForceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="url" type="string" default="https://www.google.com#anchor-name" />
    <div class="slds-var-p-around_xx-large">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-align--absolute-center">
            <div class="one" id="anchor-name">
                <a href="{!v.url}">
                            <span>Click here to Access Humira Program</span>          
                </a>           
            </div>
            <div class="one">
                <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">
                    <div class="slds-col">               
                      Click here to Access Skyrizi Program
                    </div>
                </a>    
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Hi @Dhanik, Does this advice apply to links to public external web sites such as `https://www.google.com` here?

Comment: I feel, It is not written in documentation. But in one of post sfdxfox mentioned that it will not create issue in external source. So not sure about it.